# Multiple Firebase Realtime Database in one Angular Project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to figure how to switch between using two Firebase projects using one single Angular project at the same time. I want something like:

I have the environment file

```
firebase: {
    'Firebase1': {
      apiKey: ...
    },
    'Firebase2': {
      apiKey: ...
      
    }
```

Can I do something like

```
imports[
...
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase.Firebase1)
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase.Firebase2)
...
]
```

And then in my service/component I can just use it like:

```
constructor(
    @Inject('Firebase1') db1
    @Inject('Firebase2') db2
  ) {
     db1.sth()
     db2.sth()
...
}
```

I've been searching a lot online but most of the guides and syntax seems to be out-dated from the current version of AngularFire.

Can someone help or provide me with any helpful resources?